# Impossible classname for ExtensionObjects

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am using `Milo` to browse the capabilities of servers.

This also involves decoding `ExtensionObjects` (which works fine for the `UnifiedAutomationReadCustomDataTypeExample`).

On `open62541` and milo servers it fails strangely, as `ExtensionObjects` cannot be cast to `ExtensionObjects` - please note the "[L" in the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.ExtensionObject; cannot be cast to org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.ExtensionObject
```

Is this a bug in `Milo` or am I missing something?

I am using the latest Eclipse to compile both Server and Client.
I am using `Milo 0.2.3` from `Maven`.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about how to reproduce this? Btw, the error is basically saying it can't cast an `ExtensionObject[]` to `ExtensionObject`. Without a stack trace I can't guess where this might be happening.

Comment: Yep, had to find out that Variant.getValue() can be an Object[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was produced by casting an `Object[]` to an `Object`. The code below now works properly.

```
if(rd.getDisplayName().getText().equals("OutputArguments")) {

    DataValue readServiceResult = client.readValue(100, TimestampsToReturn.Both, rd.getNodeId().local().get()).get();
    Variant args =readServiceResult.getValue();

    NodeId ni = args.getDataType().get();

    Object[] oVal = (Object[])args.getValue();
    Object val = oVal[0];
    if(val instanceof ExtensionObject) {
        ExtensionObject eo = (ExtensionObject)oVal[0];
        Object o = eo.decode();
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```